# Linux : create shared memory segment from shell command

Tags: ipc, shared-memory

I'd like to create a shared memory segment from a Unix startup script.
The created segment would be accessed by several php scripts.

Is there a shell command to create a shared mem segment specifying key, mode, permissions and size?

Comment: Avoid using SysV shared memory. It has awkward creation/cleanup semantics, as you've probably already noticed, and it's inherently unsynchronized, so it's impossible to use safely without getting other synchronization primitives involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ipcrm](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_ipcrm.htm) to delete a shared memory segment, and [ipcs](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_ipcs.htm) to list shared memory segments ... but AFAIK you need to use a C program (or equivalent) to create a shared memory segment.  There's no command I'm aware of to create one directly from the shell.

Answer (score 19):

Use ipcmk.  I never used it myself, so use

```
man ipcmk
```

Comment: it works: ipcmk -M 12345; ipcs -m | grep 12345 # 0x7900c5ed 851988     dino       644        12345      0